# In Weaviate, how to update invertedIndexConfig of an existing class?

Tags: weaviate

From this Weaviate [documentation](https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/api/rest/schema#update-a-class) - below endpoint:

```
PUT v1/schema/{class_name}
```

should allow me to alter an existing class in the schema. I wanted to set **invertedIndexConfig > indexNullState** to `true` for me to be able to use filter by `null` state.

Here's the CURL I am trying to use so far:

```
curl \
-X PUT \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer {{WEAVIATE_API_KEY}}" \
-d '{
      "class": "Player",
      "invertedIndexConfig": {
        "indexNullState": true,
        "bm25": {
            "b": 0.75,
            "k1": 1.2
        },
        "cleanupIntervalSeconds": 60,
        "stopwords": {
            "additions": null,
            "preset": "en",
            "removals": null
        }
      }
    }' \
{{WEAVIATE_HOST}}/v1/schema/Player
```

but got this error instead

```
{
"error": [
    {
        "message": "properties cannot be updated through updating the class. Use the add property feature (e.g. \"POST /v1/schema/{className}/properties\") to add additional properties"
    }
]
```

}

Hence, is it possible via this endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As of July of 2023](https://forum.weaviate.io/t/in-weaviate-how-to-update-invertedindexconfig-of-an-existing-class/296/2) isn't not possible to add this kind of index.  You'll need to create a new class, and reload all the data.

Comment: Note: You can use the cursor API in order to read all objects: https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/manage-data/read-all-objects